# What reliable sources (paid or free) exist for fossil fuel infrastructure data?

Tags: data, united-states, infrastructure

I am trying to find GIS data for various types of petroleum and natural gas infrastructure (pipelines, refineries, gathering lines, pump stations, etc). I've found quite a few sources, mostly for-profit companies selling the data. However, without spending thousands of dollars on the data, it's hard to know what I'd be getting from any of these vendors. Most of them state the resolution of the data but I'm more concerned with the completeness of it. I've also found several government sources, which seem to offer more reliable data but the different layers I'm interested in are scattered across several agencies or just not available. So,

I'm interested in data in the US in this case.

The sources I've found so far include:

**Paid**: [Platts](http://www.platts.com/products/gisdata), [MAPSearch](http://www.mapsearch.com/gis-asset-data.html), [HTSI](http://htsi-corp.com/index.html), [Rextag](http://www.rextagstrategies.com/gismain)

**Free**: [U.S. Energy Information Administration](http://www.eia.gov/), [National Pipeline Mapping System](https://www.npms.phmsa.dot.gov/default.htm) (restricted access)

Comment: how large is the area you want coverage for?

Comment: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:man_made%3Dpipeline  OSM is going to be more accurate then the government data in my experience, iv worked for a natural gas company and a government contractor mapping out pipeline

Comment: I'm looking for data spanning six US states (not all of every one of them, but a big area).

Comment: I would try Open street map (search the site if you are unsure about how to extract data) and see if you get the results you want, i don't believe the two free sources you listed cover gathering lines. You can check the accuracy on open street map by try to find the pipeline (scars, right-of-ways, occasional above ground) using wells, compressor facilities, refineries, valve sites, etc as guidelines when connecting pipelines. I have NO idea on paid GIS information